# How to submit a tar.gz file in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, python-venv

I m on client deploy mode and I would like to submit an application consisting a `tar.gz` that contains the runtime, code and libraries.

The purpose is not depend upon spark cluster for a specific python runtime (e.g. spark cluster has python 3.5 version and my code needs 3.7 version) or a library that is not installed on the cluster.

I found it was possible to submit a python file as well as for `.jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

Use venv to use a virtual environment version of python for the pyspark job.

Command once your venv is setup:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled=true  --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type=native --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.requirements=<requirementsFile> --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path=<virtualenv_path> --conf spark.pyspark.python=<python_path> <pyspark_file>
```

Have a look at: [Using VirtualEnv with PySpark](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Using-VirtualEnv-with-PySpark/ta-p/245905)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this link is very helpful. Unfortunately, the cluster prerequisites are not met : the cluster is not connected to Internet (my company is not allowing it....no comment). Having the ability to package everything in `tar.gz` would solve the problem. Any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this within Python

```py
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("module.zip")
```

Or you could do

```sh
spark-submit --py-files module.zip yourapp.py
```

See also [the Spark API here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.addPyFile)